# Resurce #nr returned instead of file name

Tags: php

I am playing with a PHP simple language file translation. So far it works, except a message, where I expect to have the name of newly created language file coming correctly from the form input. T script returns "#3" instead of a file name.
Where is my failure in this code? There are things that do not yet work, but I am going step-by-step solving problems. My intention is to read any of existing language files into the form, choose the "target" language, write translations and save new file with properly formated array.

```html
<?php 
//Initializing variable
$new_lang = ""; 
$new_lang = isset($_GET['new_lang']) ? $_GET['new_lang'] : '';
$new_lang = !empty($_GET['new_lang']) ? $_GET['new_lang'] : ''; 
$dir_flag = '';
$new_lang_one = isset($_GET['new_lang_one']) ? $_GET['new_lang_one'] : '';
$new_lang_two = isset($_GET['new_lang_two']) ? $_GET['new_lang_two'] : '';
// parse language files and assign translation
function lang($string){
  global $base_lang, $tr;
  if(isset($base_lang) AND $base_lang!="en" AND file_exists("languages/{$base_lang}.php") && strlen($base_lang) <=3) {
    include("languages/{$base_lang}.php");
      if (isset($lang[$string]) && !empty($lang[$string])) {
          return $lang[$string];
      }
  }
    return $string;
} 

// check what language files are available
function langList(){
 $dir_langs = 'languages/';
 $dir_flag = './core/flags/';
 // Open a directory, and read its contents
 if(is_dir($dir_langs)){
  if($opendirectory = opendir($dir_langs)){
   while(($lang_file = readdir($opendirectory)) !== false){
    if($lang_file != '.' && $lang_file != '..' && $lang_file != '.php'){
    echo '<a href="?lang='.pathinfo($lang_file)['filename'].'"><img src='.$dir_flag.pathinfo($lang_file)['filename'].'.gif></a> ';
    }
   }
   closedir($opendirectory);
  }
 }
}

// switch language
$base_lang="en"; // Set the default language
  if(isset($_COOKIE["lang"])){
   $base_lang=$_COOKIE["lang"]; // Get language from cookie
  }

  if(isset($_GET["lang"])){
    setcookie("lang",strip_tags($_GET["lang"]),strtotime('+30 days'),'/', NULL, 0);
    $base_lang=strip_tags($_GET["lang"]); // Or set cookie and new language
  }

// write the new_language file
echo pathinfo($new_lang)['filename'];
if(!isset($_GET['new_lang'])){
  $new_lang = fopen("./languages/".$new_lang.".php", 'w') or die("Failed to create file"); 
  $msg = "<div class='msg error'>SPECIFY NEW TARGET LANGUAGE FOR TRANSLATION!</div>";
 }else{
 $new_lang = fopen("./languages/".$new_lang.".php", 'w') or die("Failed to create file"); 
  $content = $lang['one'].'<br>'.$new_lang_one.'<br>'.$new_lang_two;
 fwrite($new_lang, $content) or die("Could not write to file"); 
 fclose($new_lang); 
 $msg = "<div class='msg success'>THE FILE <span>".$new_lang.".php</span> IS PREPARED.</div>";
}
?>
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./core/stylesheet.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <form action="" name="translator" method="get">
    <?php echo $msg;?>
    <fieldset>
     
     <div class="select_source">
      <div>Select translation FROM language:</div>

      <div class="flags">
       <?php echo langList();?>
      </div> 
      <div class="break"></div>
     </div>
     <div>
      <label>Select translatin TO language:</label>
      <input type="text" name="new_lang" placeholder="e.g.: nl, dk, it" value="">
     </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
     <table>
      <tr>
       <th>Source language key</th>
       <th>Source language string</th>
       <th><?php echo '<img src="./core/flags/'.$base_lang.'.gif" title="'.$base_lang.'">';?> Target language key</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="key"><?php echo lang('one');?></td>
       <td><?php echo lang('one');?></td>
       <td class="new_string"><textarea name="new_lang_one"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="key"><?php echo lang('two');?></td>
       <td><?php echo lang('two');?></td>
       <td class="new_string"><textarea name="new_lang_two"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="key"><?php echo lang('three');?></td>
       <td><?php echo lang('three');?></td>
       <td class="new_string"><textarea name="new_lang_three"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="key"><?php echo lang('one');?></td>
       <td><?php echo lang('one');?></td>
       <td class="new_string"><textarea name="new_lang_four"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="key"><?php echo lang('vide');?></td>
       <td><?php echo lang('vide');?></td>
       <td class="new_string"><textarea name="new_lang_vide"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="key"><?php echo lang('six');?></td>
       <td><?php echo lang('six');?></td>
       <td class="new_string"><textarea name="new_lang_six"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="key"><?php echo lang('seven');?></td>
       <td><?php echo lang('seven');?></td>
       <td class="new_string"><textarea name="new_lang_seven"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="key"><?php echo lang('eight');?></td>
       <td><?php echo lang('eight');?></td>
       <td class="new_string"><textarea name="new_lang_eight"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="key"><?php echo lang('nine');?></td>
       <td><?php echo lang('nine');?></td>
       <td class="new_string"><textarea name="new_lang_nine"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="key"><?php echo lang('ten');?></td>
       <td><?php echo lang('ten');?></td>
       <td class="new_string"><textarea name="new_lang_ten"></textarea></td>
      </tr>

     </table>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <div class="button">
         <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </fieldset>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That looks you are taking url `#3` as file name

Comment: I don't know where goes the "#3" from.

Answer (score 0):

```html
// write the new_language file
// echo pathinfo($new_lang)['filename'];
$new_lang_file = pathinfo($new_lang)['filename'];
if(!isset($_GET['new_lang'])){
  $new_lang = fopen("./languages/".$new_lang.".php", 'w') or die("Failed to create file"); 
  $msg = "<div class='msg error'>SPECIFY NEW TARGET LANGUAGE FOR TRANSLATION!</div>";
 }else{
 $new_lang = fopen("./languages/".$new_lang.".php", 'w') or die("Failed to create file"); 
  $content = '
   <?php'."\r\n".'
   // Name: '.$new_lang.'.php'."\r\n".
   '$lang = array'."\r\n".
   $new_lang_one."\r\n".$new_lang_two;
 fwrite($new_lang, $content) or die("Could not write to file"); 
 fclose($new_lang); 
 $msg = "<div class='msg success'>THE FILE <span>".$new_lang_file.".php</span> IS PREPARED.</div>";
}
```

I have modified this part of code and the "#3" is gone. The message is correct now. So now I have to study how to load the language file into the form and save the third column into a new language file.